# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error de php y myqsli.?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, formularios

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con ajax, php y mysqli para verificar de forma inmediata si un email existe, pero a la hora de escribir el mail sale este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::numRows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\send.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\send.php on line 12

Php - mysqli code:
include 'data.php';

```
if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Email='" . $_POST["email"] . "'";
  $user_count = $conn->numRows($query);
  if($user_count>0) {
      echo "<span class='estado-no-disponible-email'> Email no Disponible.</span>";
  }else{
      echo "<span class='estado-disponible-email'> Email Disponible.</span>";
  }
}
```

data.php code:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";  // Host
$username = "root";  //User
$password = ''; // Password
$dbname = "registro"; // dbname

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);

$connp = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

}
```

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), el método `numRows()` no existe, se accede a la variable `num_rows` o usas el método `mysqli_num_rows()`. La documentación está para leerla, especialmente la de PHP, que siempre tiene un montón de ejemplos y snippets!

Comment: El problema es que aún implementando el método mysqli_num_row sigue dándome el mismo error, luego no sé qué puede estar ocasionándolo @Benito-B

Comment: Debes ejecutar la consulta antes de tratar de acceder a resultados. Te recomiendo leer la documentación de [mysqli->query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)